# regex for stripping the last 2 columns of data separated by a seperator

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have following content:

```
JAHR;Unternehmens;IDOACDM;OAAAAA;BBBBB;CCCCCC
2012;FIRM5385839;4234242;23132213;ADCAS;sajkdk
```

how do i remove the LAST TWO columns seperated by the ; with reg ex...

i already found the http://rubular.com/r/et9US16DZa and this nice one, but i cant get the inverse expression of this nice little thing...

```
([^;]*\;){1}[^;]*$
```

Cheers and Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Notepad++`

**Find what :** `(;[^;]*){2}$`

**Replace with :** *(leave it empty)*

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hD2wW1)

Comment: Good one. *Slight* optimization: `(?:;[^;]*){2}$`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, every solution has done its job. And this page is also a little bit nicer to the other one!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
search: (;[^;]*){2}(?=\r?\n|$)
replace: nothing
```

Comment: Casimir, isn't `(?=\r?\n|$)` redundant? I mean a simple `$` should be enough, no?

Comment: @psxls: not necessarily, since `$` matches the end of a line only in a multiline mode, by default `$` matches only the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, I would understand that if the question was about a regex in Perl, PHP, Python etc. But the Replace dialog in Notepad++ behaves as if the `/m` modifier is always on.